# Как в Python выполнять код, который введет пользователь?

Tags: python, python-3.x

например

```
what_do = input('сюда введите выполняемый код')
```

скажем, что

```
what_do = "print('привет мир! Это мой очередной вопрос на форуме')"
```

тогда как выполнить этот код ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться стандартной функцией `exec`:

```py
>>> s = "print(\"hello, world!\")"
>>> exec(s)
hello, world!
```

Крайне не советую прибегать к этому методу, поскольку он имеет серьёзные проблемы с безопасностью - применять его можно **только** тогда, когда вы уверенны, что исполняемый скрипт **не является вредоносным**.

Дело в том, что он выполняет **любой** предоставляемый ему код, а возможностей к предоставлению кода у python достаточно, вплоть до контроля файловой системы на том уровне, на котором есть права у самого интерпретатора python.